# Embedding sounds in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, audio

I know there are a lot of threads with this same topic, but for a reason I don't understand yet, this is not working for me.

I have this project tree:

[image: Project Tree]

I embedded the alarm.wav to the .resx file from the Project->Properties->Resources menu.

I tried different combinations of code but nothing works.

At the moment this is the code I'm trying.

```
using System;
using System.Media;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Resources;
using AlarmForm;

namespace Alarm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool estado = false;
        private SoundPlayer sonido;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            sonido = new SoundPlayer(resources.GetStream("alarma"));
        }
    }
}
```

### No error is displayed during the compilation or the runtime, but instead of the sound an error beep is heard.

**Edited:** Error I found trying to use Alarm.Properties

[image: Alarm.Properties Error]

Comment: May you please describe what are you trying to exactly do? :)

Comment: The first thing you should do is split things up so you can see where it's failing. That is, `var sound = resources.GetStream("alarma");`. If that fails, the exception that it throws might shed some light on the subject.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY I'm trying to embed a sound in a project to play it when the user do certain actions.

Comment: @Memochipan Thanks for providing the information. I've posted an answer :)

Comment: @JimMischel I split it but it is not error.

Comment: if you have problems with the wav format... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/d30a3002-a553-4bb2-b8da-058255395a5e/.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY you got it I had to use using AlarmForm.Properties; instead of using Alarm.Properties; Thak you very much.

Comment: @Memochipan No problems. Glad I could help. I was about to upload a screenshot to help diagnose the problem. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to use `resources.GetStream()` while you can link the file directly using `Alarm.Properties`? I believe that it'd be much easier. I see that you've also forgot to play the Sound file linked to `sonido` which represents a new `SoundPlayer`. Here's a simple example that shows how to use `SoundPlayer`

**Example**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Resources;
using System.Media;
using AlarmForm.
using AlarmForm.Properties; //Required to call 'Resources' directly

namespace Alarm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool estado = false;
        private SoundPlayer sonido;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(Form1)); //We do not actually need this
            sonido = new SoundPlayer(Resources.alarma); //Initialize a new SoundPlayer linked to our sound file (or Alarm.Properties.Resources.alarma if Alarm.Properties was not imported)
            sonido.Play(); //Required if you would like to play the file
        }
    }
}
```

**Notice that**: You may stop the `SoundPlayer` from playing anytime by doing `sonido.Stop()` since `sonido` which represents a new class of name `SoundPlayer` was defined under `public partial class Form1: Form` UNLESS if the void that is trying to call `sonido` is static.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: I tried your code and others similar but I get an error that says something like the Properties namespace can't be found in the Alarm namespace.

Comment: @Memochipan Did you try to add `using Alarm.Properties;`? Based on the code you provided above, the name space of your application is `Alarm`. Have a great day :)

Comment: Of course, that is the line that produces the error. Look the question I added an image. Thanks for your help.